# Call a factory from a constructor?

Tags: java

I'm coding a program to manage reservations and for that I have a class Reservation and a class ReservationFactory.

Im trying to create a new reservation using the factory but im getting this problem:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getReservation() from the type ReservationFactory"

```
public class Reservation {

   public Reservation() {
       ReservationFactory.getReservation();
   }

   public Reservation(int code) {
       this.code = code;
   }
}

   class ReservaFactory {

       public Reservation getReservation() {
            Reservation r = new Reservation(this.getCode());
            return r;
       }

       public int getCode() {
           return this.code;
       }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call the factory in the constructor in your code. Instead, call the factory from the code where you need to create new instance(s) of `Reservation`.

Comment: The reservation has a unique code, im using the factory to manage the codes

Comment: But it doesn't have anything to do with what I said.

Comment: Just remove the no-arg constructor.  Make your factory public instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main (if not whole) point about factory methods/classes is to reduce the need for or eliminate direct constructor calls.

What you're trying to do is technically impossible. From a constructor, a call to a different method returning the same type as the one being constructed can only result in 2 objects, or an expected exception, or a stack overflow error (I'm probably missing some outcomes here, but I can't imagine that any would be desirable).

Alternative patterns using a factory include:

```
public class Reservation {

   //Hide the constructor
   private Reservation() {
   }

   private Reservation(int code) {
       this.code = code;
   }

   //Use a factory method in the same class
   public static Reservation instance(int code) {
       Reservation r = new Reservation();
       r.code = code;

       return r;
   }

   //A builder class, which could also be declared externally
   public static class Builder {

       //optional parameter
       private int code;

       public Reservation getReservation() {
           return new Reservation(this.code());
       }

       //A "setter" enabling fluent API
       public Builder code(int code) {
           this.code = code;
           return this;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the default private constructor

Comment: And you can simply do `new Reservation(code)` in `instance` method

Comment: @user7 That's right, that constructor isn't needed in this code; just as it doesn't have to be deleted (it may be used). This is just an example.

Answer (score -1):

The factory method is decided runtime which object is going to be instantiated.
Lets assume you have abstract class as Reservation.

```
public abstract class Reservation {

   public Reservation() {
       ReservationFactory.getReservation();
   }

   public Reservation(int code) {
       this.code = code;
   }
   abstract void bookTicket();
}
```

You may have two classes such as `RailwayReservation` and `AirLineReservation`. Which extends base class Reservation.

```
public class RailwayReservation extends Reservation {
     public RailwayReservation(int code){
           super(code);
     }
     void bookTicket(){
           System.out.println("Railaway Reservation call");
     }
}
 public class AirlineReservation extends Reservation {
     public AirlineReservation(int code){
           super(code);
     }
     void bookTicket(){
           System.out.println("Railaway Reservation call");
     }
 }
```

Then for instantiating an object of Reservation class `ReservationFactory` you are creating. ReservationFactory will give you a `Reservation`'s class object on the bases of your input.

Let's take a choice, If you call getReservation with `id = 1` then it will return RailwayReservation's instance and `id=2` then it will return AirlineReservation's instance.

```
  class ReservaFactory {
       public static Reservation getReservation(int id, int code) {
            Reservation r = null;
            if(id==1){
                 r = new RailwayReservation();
            }else if(id==2){
                 r = new AirlineReservation();
            }
            return r;
       }
}
```

We can call it by using following method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
       Reservervaion r1 = ReservationFactory.getReservation(1,100);
       Reservervaion r2 = ReservationFactory.getReservation(2,101);

 }
```